# Disallow forward date input (CCK Date)

Tags: entities, datetime

How do I disallow future dates in CCK date field?

Answer (score 1):

Check out

```
http://drupal.org/node/751826
```

and look into forms validation.  You could check if your date is less than the current date and if not, bzzzzt.

Comment: sorry, where do i put my codes

Comment: you would have to create a custom validation function, it would go in a module or theme depending on how you wanted to do it.